# How to pass enum value from robot test case to backend java function or method?

Tags: java, robotframework, jython

Robot Test:

```
find Venue Mappers With Aps And Wlans          ${userLoginHandler}     ${1}        NetworkType.OPEN_NETWORK
```

Java Code:

```
public static ArrayList<VenueMapper> findVenueMappersWithApsAndWlans(UserLoginHandler userLoginHandler, int numberOfAPs, NetworkType networkType)
```

I get this error message: 3rd arg can't be coerced to infra.model.enums.NetworkType

So how can I pass enum value from Robot Framework Suite file?

Comment: NetworkType is the enum here.

Comment: In Robot Framework `NetworkType.OPEN_NETWORK` would be considered a string. Did you do something to cast it to a java type?